# Express server add ssl

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, ssl

I followed the angular server-side rendering tutorial and created an express server. 
How can I add SSL support?

I found how to add SSL in server.js but I don't know how to add it in Typescript.

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {

    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,

    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

——————

I used a Reverse Proxy instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import the `fs` and `https` module

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import * as https from 'https';
```

Now create an object to set the key and certificate paths.

```
const options = {
    key: readFileSync('./ssl/privatekey.pem'),
    cert: readFileSync('./ssl/certificate.pem'),
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(PORT , function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + PORT);
});
```

Comment: I got the success message in the log. But I can only access the server via HTTP